# Performance of regression models

Tags: regression, correlation, model-evaluation, regression-coefficients

If we have to choose between two regression models, one has a
correlation coefficient of 0.95 and the other has a correlation coefficient of 0.75. Is it always the case that the first model is to be preferred over the other if we are interested in optimizing predictive performance?

Comment: Ponder this: it is always possible to raise the $R^2$ in a model to $1.00$ by throwing in enough independent "explanatory" variables, whether or not they are related to the response (dependent) variable.  What effect do you suppose the addition of such variables would have on predictive performance?

Answer (score 1):

**NO** If you want to optimize predictive performance, look at a measure of predictive performance (such as MSR) directly, not at R-squared. And, that measure should either be calculated on an hold-out sample, or by cross validation (alternative some information criterion such as AIC).

See also the comment by whuber:  "Ponder this: it is always possible to raise the $R^2$ in a model to 1.00 by throwing in enough independent "explanatory" variables, whether or not they are related to the response (dependent) variable. What effect do you suppose the addition of such variables would have on predictive performance?"

Comment: And check the absolute accuracy of both models in an unbiased way (using the bootstrap, cross-validation, or a huge holdout sample) using smooth nonparametric high-resolution calibration curves.